# Subset the data based on a unique value in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data below

```
test=data.frame("name"=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","C"), value=c(10,11,12,13,14,15,16))
```

I want to subset the test data based on non-repeated name "C", I want to show the data below:

```
name value
   c    16
```

I try `test[table(test$name)>1,]`, but the output was wrong.

Please give me some hint, thanks!!

Comment: following on your logic you could do: `test[test$name==names(which(table(test$name)==1)),]` or you could use `library(dplyr)` and do `test%>%
  group_by(name)%>%
  filter(length(name)==1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `data.frame` as such,

```
table.freq <- as.data.frame(table(test$name))
test[test$name %in% table.freq$Var1[table.freq$Freq==1],]
#  name value
#7    C    16
```

or using `which`

```
test[test$name %in% names(which(table(test$name)==1)),]
#  name value
#7    C    16
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(test)`), grouped by 'name', `if` the number of rows is equal to 1 (`.N==1`), subset the data.table.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test)[, if(.N==1) .SD, by = name]
#   name value
#1:    C    16
```

Answer (score 2):

We can try `ave` function in `base R` and select only the group with `length = 1`

```
test[ave(test$value, test$name, FUN = function(x) length(x)) == 1, ]

# name value
#7    C    16
```

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
test %>%
   group_by(name) %>%
   filter(n() == 1)

#   name value
#   <fctr> <dbl>
#1     C    16
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternate code for `data.frame`:

```
test <-
  data.frame(
   name = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "D"),
   value = c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17)
)

test[test$name == unique(test$name)[table(test$name) == 1], ]
# Answer:
# name value
# 7    C    16
# 8    D    17
```

Or:

```
test[test$name == names(table(test$name))[table(test$name) == 1], ]
```

Comment: I feel using `%in%` would be a better approach instead of `==` as the former will pick more than one unique variable present. But this can also be a  solution for this as there is only one unique variable in this object.